# How can we Retrive the 3gp file from sdcard into our application?

Tags: android

I'm new to Andriod development and was wondering how I could retrieve the `3gp` file from an SD card into my application?

Comment: Don't hurry the community up. We are not obligated to help you but we're doing it on our own will. Be polite and descriptive and you'll get the answer.

Comment: I've revised your question. Please take note of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this (one of the many way to do that)

```
String FilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/your/file/directory"+ "YOURFILENAME";
File 3gpFile = new File(FilePath);
```

now go ahead and use 3gpFile to do other stuff
remember to have uses-permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```